# WP7 what is E_FAIL

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio-playback-agent

I'm using `AudioPlayerAgent` to build music application on Windows Phone 7.
However, when handle `OnPlayStateChanged` event in the agent, I usually receive **E_FAIL** error when handle `TrackEnded` event

```
case PlayState.TrackReady:
     player.Play();
     break;
```

So what is E_FAIL and how to deal with it ? Try catch is not a good solution here

Comment: What is the full exception message and stack trace?

Comment: @SLaks it only give E_FAIL message, there's nothing wrong with other call in stack trace. And E_FAIL sometimes happens :(